# How to display label in view by combining different class members in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I Want to display label for input box but I have 3 different class which contains information

Like Class1 [Settings] is like this

```
public class Settings
{
    public static decimal Setting1 { get; set; }
    public static decimal Setting2 { get; set; }
}
```

we are populating data in above class at the time of login, so we kept it in session

My Class2 [AppConst] is like this

```
public static class AppConst
{
    public const string _unitPersentage = "%";
    public const string _unitPerMT = "Per MT";
}
```

and my Modal is like this

```
public class Sale
{
    [Display(Name = "Discount")]
    public double DiscountAmount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Road Tax")]
    public double RoadTaxAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my View for Model "Sale" I want to display label for property "DiscountAmount" like this

Discount 5% (Lable of DiscountAmount + Value of Settings.Setting1 + value of AppConst._unitPersentage)

Here I can get label for "DiscountAmount" by using

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.DiscountAmount)
```

but how can I display value of tow other members "Settings.Setting1" & "AppConst._unitPersentage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten out your model and then use an editor template to show that complex label.

### The Flatten Model

```
public class CustomModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Discount")]
    public double DiscountAmount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Road Tax")]
    public double RoadTaxAmount { get; set; }   
    public decimal Setting1 { get; set; }
    public string UnitPercent {get;set;}
}
```

### The Template

The template should be placed inside the `EditorTemplates` folder under the `Shared` folder.

```
@model CustomModel

@{
    var inputProp = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties
        .First(o => o.PropertyName == "DiscountAmount");
}
<label for="@inputProp.PropertyName" id="@(inputProp.PropertyName+"Label")">
    Discount 5% (@inputProp.ShortDisplayName @Model.Setting1@Model.UnitPercent)
    <input id="@inputProp.PropertyName" type="text"
        name="@inputProp.PropertyName" />    
</label>
```

### Controller Code

This is how you will create and pass the model to your view:

```
return View(new CustomModel
{
    // get it from your datastore or where ever the source may be
    Setting1 = getFromDbOrSomewhere(),
    UnitPercent = AppConst._unitPersentage,                
});
```

### Your View

Then consume it on your view like this

```
@model CustomModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => Model)
```

The beauty of this approach is that you can always discard the template and do inline html in your view. Also, the logic of having an "input + label" for your model is separated into one place.

Answer (score 0):

You have few alternatives to try. If the data is only for display purpose you may use - ViewData or ViewBag or TempData to pass the values for Settings and AppConst, whatever suits your purpose. See [here](http://www.rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications).

In this case, if these are static objects, you may refer them in the view as:
`<Namespace>.Settings.Setting1` or `<Namespace>.AppConst._unitPerMT`.

> Please take this as a starting point and follow proper best practices for development. Please do not declare `public` members with underscore. Underscores are generally prefixed to `private` members.

Comment: I will use those value in JavaScript also for further calculation, at the time of some value entered on other text box, so I have to refer that label ("Settings.Setting1" & "AppConst._unitPersentage") by their ID

Comment: @NeerajGupta, if it is just to be used for calculations and not to be returned back, you may assign these values to some `var` or `hidden-input`.